# Scroll to top of next item in a recyclerview

Tags: java, android, swipe, gesture, ontouchlistener

I have the following code  which detects that whether a swipe in onTouch is Left / Right. But i want to detect top/down. Please suggest changes in the code as to how i can achieve that by modifying the code

```
r.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int downX = 0,upX;
            switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                    downX = (int) event.getX();}
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                    upX = (int) event.getX();

                    float deltaX = downX - upX;
                    Log.e("DeltaX","Dd "+deltaX);
                     if(Math.abs(deltaX)>0){
                        if(deltaX>=0){

                            return true;
                        }else{

                            return  true;
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

*Please dont suggest any 3 rd party libraries or any other solution. Please suggest changes in the above code only. I have tried a lot of other things, but this is a perfect fit*

Thank you for responding!

Comment: why don't you get event.getY() and work the same logic?

Comment: Could you please post a solution ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code i figured out

```
  r.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        public boolean top;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);


            if (top) {
                int index = mLay.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                r.smoothScrollToPosition(index);

            } else {
                int index = mLay.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                r.smoothScrollToPosition(index);


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (dy > 0) {
                top = false;
            } else {

                top = true;
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: my recycler have a bug with this code, its automatically always scrolling